# Want to Echo variable which is inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, forms, oop, insert

I have a OOP program in php to insert data into mysql database.. it is working fine but the problem is that i want to echo the $msg when the data is inserted to display that data is successfully inserted or Error.

```
<?php 
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("OOP_php",$conn);

class insertdata{
function insert($name,$city,$country){
    $msg;
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into OOP (name,City,Country) values('$name','$city','$country')");
    if($sql){

     $msg= "Successfully inserted"; 
    }
    else{
        $msg="Error!";
    }

}
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br /><br />
City: <input type="text" name="city" /><br /><br />
Country: <input type="text" name="country" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$in=new insertdata();
$in->insert($name,$city,$country);
echo $in->msg;


}

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn about `$this` and class properties. Or about `return` statement

Comment: You dosn't need var $msg just use echo.

Comment:  if you're going to get into some fancy OOP programming, why are you messing around with an api that's in deprecation/deletion? Not to mention being unsafe; use a prepared statement. You're just going to have to rewrite it completely later on when that server of yours no longer supports that api.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Try to avoid `echo` in class methods if you don't have any real reason to do it. Return false/true/numbers to show success/fail.

Comment: tadmad... I have just started learning PDO and not much familiar with it , so m a newbie in that , that'y i used mysql_query

Comment: @Inam if you're going to address someone personally, you need to use the `@username` syntax. He may not be present in the question anymore. Bit of a Stack tip.

Comment: welcome, but now at this point in time and seeing a comment you left under an answer stating that it doesn't work, it's best that you start checking for errors with php's error reporting https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysql_error()` on the query.

Comment: error is not in query but in variable , i have just started OOP in Php in newbie trying to fix it from the last 1hour still failed

Comment: If you're just getting started in PHP consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: *"error is not in query but in variable"* - being what? you didn't say, nor did you mention anything about it in any answer.

Comment: I m already working on Laravel and i m using PHP from 1year but new OOP and PDO concept in php

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the string with `return $msg;`.

```
class insertdata
{
    function insert($name,$city,$country){
        $msg;
        $sql=mysql_query("insert into OOP (name,City,Country) values('$name','$city','$country')");
        if($sql) {
           $msg= "Successfully inserted"; 
        } else {
            $msg="Error!";
        }
        return $msg; // <----------
    }
}
```

and then

```
echo $in->insert($name,$city,$country);
```

PS 1: mysql_* functions are insecure and deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO with a prepared statement.

PS 2: You probably wan't to return true or false and then show a message accordingly, in some place else.

Comment: *"PS 1: mysql_* functions are insecure."* - in some instances, sure. In deprecation and deleted as per PHP 7; yes.

Answer (score 0):

set msg as a class property and access using **this** keyword, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

```
<?php 
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("OOP_php",$conn);

class insertdata{
public $msg;
function insert($name,$city,$country){

$sql=mysql_query("insert into OOP (name,City,Country) values('$name','$city','$country')");
if($sql){

 $this->msg= "Successfully inserted"; 
}
else{
    $this->msg="Error!";
}
return $this->msg;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: An explanation is always useful, rather than simply code

Comment: Oh no, no mysql_* methods please. Someone fix it until children copied it.